# Split string into array (delimited by "\ ")

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, shell

I'm currently writing a bash script. Let's assume I have the following string:

```
C:\Program Files\Folder1\ C:\Program Files\Folder2\ C:\Program Files\Folder3\
```

This string can contain an unknown amount of windows locations.
Now I need to split the string into an array at the end of each location, so each location has its own key in the array. The main problem are the spaces in every path (Program Files).

What I've tried so far:

**Using IFS variable:**

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS="\ "
myArray=( $myString )
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

The Problem here is, that it cuts the locations on every backslash, not just backslash and whitespace as it was intended. So `C:` is the first element of my array.

**Using read command:**

```
IFS="\ " read -ra myArray "$myString"
```

Same problem as before.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Edit:** I'm not using real bash but git bash on windows. So not every bash command is available.

Comment: No, because computers aren't psychic.

Comment: `bash` and `Windows` with `Windows` style paths?

Comment: My bad, I edited the string so now it should be clear what I want to do.

Comment: Yep. I'm not happy about that either, but I got the order to create a bash script that can partly do what I asked for (the use case would be git bash on windows)

Comment: On MSWin, a folder name can start with a space.

Comment: It probably can, but that doesn't matter for my specific case. I'm making sure that no folder starts with a whitespace in the string.

Comment: `echo $var | grep -Po "(.*?)(?=(\s[A-Z]:|$))"` . Well that's not complete, I hope someone may complete the rest and post it.

Comment: All characters in `IFS` are considered field separators.  This means bash will split the string on any occurrence of either backslash or space.  I believe you'd have to resort to another method of splitting your string, i.e. pre-processing it with sed or similar such that `\ ` is converted to a single character you could put into `IFS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
s='C:\Program Files\Folder1\ C:\Program Files\Folder2\ C:\Program Files\Folder3\'
IFS='^K' read -ra arr < <(sed 's/\\ /^K/g' <<< "$s")
```

**OR Non-BASH**

```
echo "$s" | sed 's/\\ /^K/g' | IFS='^K' read -ra arr
```

**Testing:**

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="C:\\Program Files\\Folder1" [1]="C:\\Program Files\\Folder2" [2]="C:\\Program Files\\Folder3\\")'
```

**PS:** Here `^K` is actually <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

---

You can also use `awk`:

```
echo "$s" | awk -F '\\\\( |$)' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i) print $i}'
C:\Program Files\Folder1
C:\Program Files\Folder2
C:\Program Files\Folder3
```

For array creation:

```
IFS=';' arr=($(echo "$s" | awk -F '\\\\( |$)' -v ORS=';' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
     if ($i) print $i}'))
```

Comment: This gives me two different errors: `cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented` and `ambiguous redirect`- probably because I'm using git bash on windows and not real bash?

Comment: oh ok you can use: `echo "$s" | sed 's/\\ /^K/g' | IFS='^K' read -ra arr` also.

Comment: Also added an `awk` version in my answer.

Comment: Your non-Bash version doesn't print anything at all. The awk version works, but this only prints the items and doesnt put them in an array for later use. I tried editing the code so everything goes into an array, but with no luck (no awk skills...)

Comment: Why do you want it in a BASH array when you don't even have a standard BASH to work with. The reason why other `read` based commands aren't working because your BASH has very limited features hence BASH arrays may not work as you want. Better to take awk output and store it in a temp file to process it later.

Comment: Well, I'm using another array in my script (filled by hand), and it works just fine. So the problem doesn't seem to be the array, it is more likely to be the initialization of the array with `read`...

Comment: Ok try this command to create array: **`IFS=';' arr=($(echo "$s" | awk -F '\\\\( |$)' -v ORS=';' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i) print $i}'))`**

Answer (score 1):

Probably no filename contains a tab, and the following will work:

```
IFS=$'\t' read -ra the_files <<<"${the_string//\\ /$'\\\t'}"
```

In the unlikely case that a filename does contain a tab, you could change the tab character above to something else, like `\1`.

Comment: This works fine... but only for the first element. The final array consists of only one element (`C:\Program Files\Folder1\`) - Any idea on that?

Comment: @JoelP: How are you printing the final array? You need to use `printf %s\\n ${the_files[@]}` or `declare -p the_files` to see its values.

Comment: Well, using your printf code I only get `C:\Program[linebreak]Files\Folder1` as output (replace [linebreak] with a real linebreak).

Comment: @JoelP: Oops, I missed the quotes on the printf command. It should have been `printf %s\\n `${the_files[@]}"`. Did you use `-ra` in the `read` command, and not just `-r`? What does `declare -p the_files` give you?

Comment: The linebreak disappeared now, but the array still only contains one element. Yes, I did use `-ra`, still no success. Because I'm using only git bash on windows, I am not able to use `declare`.

Comment: @JoelP: You should probably mention that you are using git-bash in the question. I have no idea which bash features are implemented by git-bash.

Comment: @JoelP: Are you certain that `git bash` even has arrays? Otherwise, there is nothing particularly modern in that command line.

Comment: Well, I'm using another array in my script (filled by hand), and it works just fine. So the problem doesn't seem to be the array, it is more likely to be the initialization of the array with `read`

Comment: @JoelP: Ok. I really have no idea. If you can find some solid documentation, or even a source repository, for `git bash`, I'll take a look at it. What I found in a few minutes of googling was nothing; like most Windows products, the assumption seems to be that no-one reads detailed docs anyway. The msysgit repo only has a binary for bash, so I don't even know where they got it from. Etc.

Comment: `uname` gives me `MINGW32_NT-6.1`. Does this help?

Comment: @JoelP: No. uname is about the (emulated) OS, not the shell. `bash --version` would be a little more useful, but (a) it might not work and (b) it might not really be bash, who knows? (Someone, but not I.)